# How to make rows of equal height with uneven div content in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp3Uy.png)

NOTE: I have the JQuery code below that worked for me, but I have to use Javascript.
I have a table where there are two columns.
Each row of the columns has to be the same height, but each row does not contain the exact same amount of content.
The container class "row" has 3 divs in the first column and 2 divs in the second column.

Here is my HTML

```
        <div class="table">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="value-label">TEXT1</div>
                    <div class="compare-label">TEXT2</div>
                    <div class="comment-label">TEXT3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="value-label">TEXT1</div>
                    <div class="compare-label">TEXT2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I had the height of the rows being the same working with the following JQuery function:

```
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
                            var heights = $(".row").map(function() {
                                return $(this).height();
                            }).get(),
                            maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
                            $(".row").height(maxHeight);
                            });
                    </script>
```

My issue is that my company does not allow the use of JQuery and I'm having a lot of problems trying to accomplish the same thing in Javascript.
I need the height of the row in each column to be the same, no matter the amount of divs inside of the row, but in Javascript.

UPDATE: Forgot to add that, in some situations, the 3 div column will revert to a 2 div column. So the heights need to change based on how many divs are showing. This is just an example with one row. I have 5 rows that do this across two columns.

Comment: Why not just use a `table`? Their use is only frowned on when used for layout purposes. If you're trying to present tabular data - as you are here - then their use is entirely valid.

Comment: You could use `flexbox` layout (CSS3) to achieve this. No need for any scripting.

Comment: or define min-height in your CSS

Comment: Are the divs in the row meant to be stacked or horizontal? seems a bit of a daft name to call it row if the content is in a column!

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox(CSS3) layout which I love using & recommend others to use it as well, the above can be achieved easily with just the following CSS:

```
.table {
  display: flex; // to initialize flex
  background: lightgrey;
  justify-content: center; // horizontally centers its child contents
}

.table .column {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-basis: 40%; // used similar to width property
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgrey;
  justify-content: center;
}

.table .column {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-basis: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="value-label">TEXT1</div> 
      <div class="compare-label">TEXT2</div> 
      <div class="comment-label">TEXT3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="value-label">TEXT1</div>
      <div class="compare-label">TEXT2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use JS to do this, I would do something like this

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
var heights = Array.prototype.slice
.apply(rows)
.map(function(row) {
    return row.clientHeight;
}),
maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

rows.forEach(function(row) {
    row.style.height = maxHeight + "px";
});
```

I **RECOMMEND** you to use flexbox or a css grid system like [bootstrap has](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div align="center">
  <table id="tabular" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2">
    <tr class="thead">
        <th width="10%" align="center" rowspan="2">something</th>
        <th width="20%" align="center" colspan="3">something</th>
        <th width="20%" align="center" colspan="3">something</th>
        <th width="20%" align="center" colspan="3">something</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="thead">
      <th align="center">something</th>
      <th align="center">something</th>
      <th align="center">something</th>
      <th align="center">something</th>
      <th align="center">something</th>
      <th align="center">something</th> 
      <th align="center">something</th>
      <th align="center">something</th>
      <th align="center">something</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You should really add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: display:table would work just fine when an HTML table is not really needed